# Redux and concurrent token refresh requests

Tags: javascript, redux, refresh-token

We are working on a Redux app and using thunks to encapsulate any async calls and compose multiple actions. I am coming up against an interesting problem; when the auth token expires and I hit a section of my app that has multiple concurrent calls to the api there is a race to refresh the token which results in a `200` followed my n `401`s as the winner of the race successfully refreshes the token only to leave the runners up to pass the stale token and be denied. In our implementation this results in a logout which kinda defeats the purpose of a refresh token...

Should I write a middle ware and queue any actions that result in failed refresh requests and replay them? I am unsure about a clean solution to this but I figure that there must be others having similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody wrote the middleware I was thinking about here https://github.com/esbenp/redux-refresh-token